# xray is not see kinesis application

Tags: scala, amazon-kinesis, aws-xray

I have a scala kinesis application that I am trying to instrument using xray.

It works fine locally (While running an xray deamon) but it doesn't show any traces in AWS. It has full access to xray, and there are no errors in the logs.  Is there something I need to do to make sure it knows where the deamon is running?  my code is very simple

```
  val segment = AWSXRay.beginSegment(s"my-application")
  AWSXRay.beginSubsegment("get records")
  --do some stuff
  AWSXRay.endSubsegment()
  AWSXRay.endSegment()
```

While digging around, it looks like maybe kinesis isn't supported by xray (still trying to find a full list)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the XRay daemon, you can enable debug logs to see if there is any activity going on in the daemon.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-configuration.html#xray-daemon-configuration-commandline

In the case in which the daemon isn't receiving data, keep in mind that the daemon listens for traffic on UDP port 2000, and will not receive trace data if your scala application is not on the same localhost as the XRay daemon.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon.html